# Getting the actual class of a message body

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm passing a List of different objects to a camel route. I would like the route to split the body into one object per message and put the class of the body in a header (using a processor).

```
    from("direct:in")
        .split(body())
        .process(new JmsTypeHeaderProcessor(body().getClass().getName()))
        .to("mock:out");
```

I'm trying it like this...

```
@Produce(uri = "direct:in") private ProducerTemplate template;
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:out") private MockEndpoint endpoint;

@Test
public void testRoute() throws Exception {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("String");
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(1));
    list.add(Boolean.FALSE);

    template.sendBody(list);

    for (Exchange ex : endpoint.getExchanges()) {
        System.out.println("JMSType=" + ex.getIn().getHeader("JMSType"));
    }
}
```

When I run that I find I actually have the headers

> JMSType=org.apache.camel.builder.ValueBuilder
>
> JMSType=org.apache.camel.builder.ValueBuilder
>
> JMSType=org.apache.camel.builder.ValueBuilder

whereas I expected, and would like

> JMSType=java.lang.String
>
> JMSType=java.lang.Integer
>
> JMSType=java.lang.Boolean

What is needed to get the class of the actual body?

BTW. I can see that `log("body.class")` returns what I want but I have not been able to follow how it works or adapt it for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Camel routes are designed in the route builder and the code is run once, to setup the routes.

So this code

```
.process(new JmsTypeHeaderProcessor(body().getClass().getName()))
```

Is invoked once, and body().getClass() returns the `ValueBuilder` as that is what is used at design time in the DSL to specify body etc.

If you want to access the runtime message body, then get that from the `Exchange` from the `process` method of your processor. That is the runtime message and then you can get the body.

Comment: I could swear I had tried that earlier and still got the ValueBuilder! It works now anyway. Thanks Claus.